# strpos function doesn't detect instance if it's first word in a string

Tags: php

Need to substitute piece of string with values coming from url parameter. Created a  {{hkw}} "token" for that. Works perfectly fine if substituted text is not used as a first thing in a string. But if I use it in a very beginning- nothing happens.
For example:
If I use "Substitute fullowing {{hkw}}", everything gets substituted properly.
If I use "{{hkw}} Should be substituted", nothing happens and {{hkw}} is still there.

At first, I tried this

```
     if (strpos($kwttl,'{{hkw}}') !== false)
```

After googling, I found  that following should work

```
    if (strpos($kwttl,'{{hkw}}') === true)
```

But it didn't.
Here is my full code.

```
    $fullurl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $kwttl = get_the_title();
    if (strpos($fullurl,'hkw') === true) {
        $hkwsub = $_GET['hkw'];
        if (strpos($hkwsub,'+') === true) {
            $hkwsub = str_replace('+', ' ', $hkwsub);
        } 
    } else {
        $hkwsub = '';
    }
    if (strpos($kwttl,'{{hkw}}')) {
        $kwttl = str_replace('{{hkw}}', $hkwsub, $kwttl);
    }
```

error log is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `strpos()` can return strict true is incorrect. The function `strpos()` returns either:

1. `false` if the string is not found, or
2. An integer >= 0 if the string is found

[PHP Manual Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Your full code should instead be this:

```
$fullurl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$kwttl = get_the_title();
if (strpos($fullurl,'hkw') !== false) {
    $hkwsub = $_GET['hkw'];
    if (strpos($hkwsub,'+') !== false) {
        $hkwsub = str_replace('+', ' ', $hkwsub);
    } 
} else {
    $hkwsub = '';
}
if (strpos($kwttl,'{{hkw}}') !== false) {
    $kwttl = str_replace('{{hkw}}', $hkwsub, $kwttl);
}
```

Comment: you mean `if (false !== strpos($fullurl,'hkw'))` ...lol ... I would just add that string indexes like array indexes start at 0, so a position of 0 is like saying `$string[0]`, and PHP because of it's loose typing will treat `0` as Falsy.  That is why you need to use the strict type checking `===`

Comment: PS don't tell anyone but that actually does work  `$s = 'string'; echo $s[0];`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba8739f46799e062893d5dd3820157bb7678c604) it outputs `s` .. :)